# Spring Boot Application is throwing exception when runs from Junit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Boot Application which is throwing some exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]' when runs from JUnit test.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>      
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As this pom.xml has different spring versions like spring 4.2.5.RELEASE and spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, when it runs from JUnit Test it is throwing exception:

JUnit Logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAllMergedAnnotations(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:150)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:126)
    ... 21 more
```

Any suggestion for version matching between spring and spring-boot?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the change log](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/a5139f3c6669bfb766e506b42c8916b70b77d4bf#diff-c379a0ad15cd3b7eb09f75b1d9d3a638R477), `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findAllMergedAnnotations()` has been introduced since version 4.3. So you may have to change the version from `<spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>` to `<spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>` or later.

```
 +   * @since 4.3
 +   * @see #findMergedAnnotation(AnnotatedElement, Class)
 +   */
 +  public static <A extends Annotation> Set<A> findAllMergedAnnotations(AnnotatedElement element,
 +          Class<A> annotationType) {
```

Comment: changing spring-boot-starter-test version to 1.1.4 and using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) and @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class) worked for me.

Comment: Ah, downgrading starter-test to 1.1.4. Sounds like another solution.